# Object snaps to old top (InteractJs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, interact.js

I am using InteractJs and I almost have it working but when I put the star on a tree that was small before it goes to the top of the small tree.

So when you drag the star on a tree the other trees get smaller. When you drag it to another tree the trees get normal height again but the star goes to the top of the small tree height that it used to be.

```
    interact('.draggable')
    .draggable({
        onmove: function (event) {
            var target = event.target,
                x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
                y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

            target.style.webkitTransform =
            target.style.transform =
                'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

            target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
            target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
        },
        onend: function (event) {
            var textEl = event.target.querySelector('p');

            textEl && (textEl.textContent =
                'moved a distance of '
                + (Math.sqrt(event.dx * event.dx +
                             event.dy * event.dy)|0) + 'px');
        }
    })
    .inertia(true)
    .restrict({
        drag: "parent",
        endOnly: true,
        elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
    });

interact('.draggable').snap({
      mode: 'anchor',
      anchors: [],
      range: Infinity,
      elementOrigin: { x: 0.5, y: 2 },
      endOnly: true
});

// enable draggables to be dropped into this
interact('.tree').dropzone({
    // only accept elements matching this CSS selector
    accept: '#star',
    // Require a 75% element overlap for a drop to be possible
    overlap: 0.75,

    // listen for drop related events:

    ondropactivate: function (event) {
        // add active dropzone feedback
        event.target.classList.add('drop-active');

    },
    ondragenter: function (event) {
        var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget,
            dropzoneElement = event.target;

        // feedback the possibility of a drop
        clearInterval(interval); // stop star rotation
        dropzoneElement.classList.add('drop-target');
        draggableElement.classList.add('can-drop');
        $('.tree:not(.drop-target)').find('img').animate({
            opacity: .5,
            height: "160px"
            });
        var dropRect = interact.getElementRect(event.target),
            dropCenter = {
              x: dropRect.left + dropRect.width  / 2,
              y: dropRect.top  + dropRect.height / 2
            };

        event.draggable.snap({
          anchors: [ dropCenter ]
        });

    },
    ondragleave: function (event) {
        var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget,
            dropzoneElement = event.target;
        // remove the drop feedback style
        event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
        event.relatedTarget.classList.remove('can-drop');
        $('.tree:not(.drop-target)').find('img').animate({
            opacity: 1,
            height: "186px"
            });

        event.draggable.snap(false);
    },
    ondrop: function (event) {
        //Dropped event
    },
    ondropdeactivate: function (event) {
        // remove active dropzone feedback
        event.target.classList.remove('drop-active');
        event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
    }
})

//Start star rotation
var angle = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    angle+=1;
    $("#star img").rotate(angle);
},50)
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hpq7rpnh/4/

Library: http://interactjs.io/